# How to use dynamic e.parameter with Google Apps?

Tags: textbox, widget, google-apps-script

I have created a grid in a doGet() function. This grid contains a dynamic number of rows choose by the user. In each rows i have some TextBox. I would like to be able to get all the data inserted by the user on the textboxes once the user clicked on the submit button.

So i give a dynamic ID to each textBox :

```
app.createTextBox().setName('gridText'+countRow);
countRow ++;
 .........
```

My problem is that I dont know how to dynamicaly access to my TextBox on my submit function.

I tried something like this :

```
for( i = 0 ; i < countRow ; i++){
var buffer  = e.parameter[e.parameter.gridText]+i;
 .........
}
```

based on this : http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps-script/services/nWN14AQ-9gQ

But it does'nt work... whereas this works :

```
  var buffer = e.parameter.gridText3;
```

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var buffer  = e.parameter['gridText' + i.toString()];
```